# Flask File Upload hangs when trying to upload PDF files

Tags: file, pdf, flask, upload

I've included "PDF" in my list of allowed extensions.

```
# APP CONFIG SETTINGS
app.config["DEBUG"] = True
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config["ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS"] = set(["pdf","docx","doc"])
```

Notice I have both "doc" and "docx" included in the list as well. They work perfectly fine. PDFs don't want to for some reason.

Here's the form itself:

```
<form action="upload_file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table id="submitResumeTable">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:12px;">Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="resName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:12px;">Telephone</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="resPhone"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:12px;">Email</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="resEmail">
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <p style="margin-bottom:-3px; font-size:12px">Please upload a Word or PDF file by selecting "Choose File" below:</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:12px;">Resume</td>
            <td>
                <input style="padding:0; width:100%" type="file" name="resFile">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:12px;">Message</td>
            <td>
                <textarea name="resMsg" rows="6"></textarea>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit" id="submitResBtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```

It hits this endpoint in my python file:

```
@app.route("/upload_file", methods=["POST"])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files["resFile"] 

    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename) 
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], filename))

        emailTitle = ("%s's Resume" % request.form["resName"])
        msg = Message(emailTitle,sender="test@gmail.com",recipients=["test@test.com"])
        msg.body = ("Name: %s\nPhone: %s\nE-mail: %s\n\nMessage:\n%s" % (request.form["resName"],request.form["resPhone"],request.form["resEmail"],request.form["resMsg"]))

        filepath = "static/uploads/" + filename
        splitfile = filename.split(".")
        otherpath = splitfile[0] + '/' + splitfile[1]

        with app.open_resource(filepath) as fp:
            msg.attach(filename,otherpath,fp.read())
        mail.send(msg)
    else:
        return render_template("send_resume.html", pageHeading="Send Us Your Resume", uploadStatus=2) # upload unsuccessful
    return render_template("send_resume.html", pageHeading="Send Us Your Resume", uploadStatus=1) # upload successful
```

Comment: Do you manage to send email when you upload pdf? Does `mail.send(msg)` successfully execute?